# SWT List within Group can not be scrolled

Tags: java, list, swt

I need some help with SWT.
I want to create a Scrolled List in a Group. 
I use the following code, but the size of the Group is variable and the Scrollbars are not usable. I want to have a List with a given size and if there are too many entries in the List, I want to have a Scrollbar to scroll down.

```java
    super(parent, style);

    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,false));
    Group grpSettings = new Group(this, SWT.NONE);
    grpSettings.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    grpSettings.setText("Settings");
    grpSettings.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    grpSettings.setSize(200, 200);

    Label nameLabel = new Label(grpSettings, SWT.NONE);
    nameLabel.setText("Choose");

    ScrolledComposite scroll = new ScrolledComposite(grpSettings, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    scroll.setSize(200, 200);
    scroll.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    scroll.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);

    final List list = new List(scroll, SWT.NONE); // Create a List with a vertical ScrollBar
     // Add a bunch of items to it

    for (int i=1;i < 50 ;i++ ){
        list.add("Ex" + i);
    }

    scroll.setContent(list);
    scroll.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    scroll.setExpandVertical(true);


     list.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener () {
            public void handleEvent (Event e) {
                int es = list.getSelectionIndex();
                System.out.println(es);
            }
     });
}
```

Comment: Don't try to use `setSize` on controls when you are using Layouts - the layout will override the sizes (except for the Shell).

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

The `List` widget has scrollbars of its own, hence there is no need to wrap it into a `ScrolledComposite`.

Like the snippet below illustrates, it is sufficient to create the `List` with the `V_SCROLL` style flag

```java
public static void main( String[] args ) {
  Display display = new Display();
  Shell shell = new Shell( display );
  shell.setLayout( new FillLayout() );
  Group group = new Group( shell, SWT.NONE );
  group.setText( "Group" );
  group.setLayout( new GridLayout( 1, false ) );
  Label label = new Label( group, SWT.NONE );
  label.setText( "Choose" );
  List list = new List( group, SWT.V_SCROLL );
  list.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true ) );
  for( int i = 0; i < 128; i++ ) {
    list.add( "Item " + i );
  }
  shell.setSize( 300, 300 );
  shell.open();
  while( !shell.isDisposed() ) {
    if( !display.readAndDispatch() )
      display.sleep();
  }
  display.dispose();
}
```